# Starting jupyterhub with docker

Tags: docker, jupyterhub

I am starting with docker and jupyterhub. I am following those instructions (https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/jupyterhub/). I can start jupyterhub, but I am struggling to start it with docker (dockerspawner
) and to user the oauth authentication with github. Can someone point some tutorial or give some help with this matter?

Answer (score 0):

I really like the approach by https://github.com/minrk/jupyterhub-demo. It features a makefile approach incorporating a nice automation of the necessary steps. You can adjust the bash scripts to suit your own needs. Very nice that it works as good as out of the box.

Some more tips for dockerspawner are to be found here:
https://github.com/jupyterhub/dockerspawner#configuration

He also gave a presentation some time ago: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSVvxOchT8Y